Incorrect Hibernate Mapping of OneToOne Relationships with Composite Keys in a PostgreSQL Database
I'm encountering a problem in a Spring Boot application using Hibernate, where OneToOne relationships involving entities with composite keys are not mapped correctly in a PostgreSQL database. Specifically, Hibernate maps the same entity instance to two properties in a parent entity, despite different expected results based on the underlying database entries.
Here are the simplified entity structures to illustrate the problem:
Entities:
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @EmbeddedId
    private FooId id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "alphaId", referencedColumnName = "userId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "betaId", referencedColumnName = "barId")
    })
    private Bar alphaBar;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "betaId", referencedColumnName = "userId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "alphaId", referencedColumnName = "barId")
    })
    private Bar betaBar;
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    @EmbeddedId
    private BarId id;
}

@Embeddable
public class FooId {
    private String alphaId;
    private String betaId;
}

@Embeddable
public class BarId {
    private String userId;
    private String barId;
}

Problem:
In the application, each Foo instance involves two distinct Bar instances, representing different relationships (alphaBar and betaBar). However, when retrieving Foo, both alphaBar and betaBar are populated with the same Bar instance, even though the underlying data in the PostgreSQL database for each Bar is distinct and correct.
Requirements:
Each Foo should map to two distinct Bar instances, reflecting the unique userId and barId combinations.
Correct mapping is crucial for the integrity of the application's data handling and processing.
What I've Tried:
Verified database integrity to ensure distinct and accurate data for Bar entries.
Checked the generated SQL through Hibernate's logging, which seems correct but does not align with the application's entity mapping results.
Questions:
Is there an error in how I've configured the @JoinColumns for mapping the relationships using composite keys?
Could Hibernate's caching or session management be affecting how these entities are uniquely identified and fetched in a PostgreSQL setting?
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.
Update:
Further investigation into the issue has revealed that the problem might be linked to the use of the IN clause in the SQL generated by Hibernate. Despite configuring @JoinColumns for my OneToOne relationships and expecting Hibernate to use an inner join to fetch each associated Bar instance distinctly, the framework still utilizes an IN clause which seems to be causing incorrect entity mapping.
I am seeking advice on how to force Hibernate to utilize an explicit inner join without resorting to an IN clause, or any configurations that might prevent this behavior. Insights into how Hibernate handles such complex entity relationships and any potential misconfigurations in my setup would be highly appreciated.

Can you share the resulting definitions for Foo and Bar tables you see in PostgreSQL? Also, can you show the in vs inner join difference you're suspecting? There's nothing wrong with using an in as the inner join condition, these aren't mutually exclusive and don't really serve the same purpose.

The problem is in the two @JoinColumns in PostgreSQL, alphaId and betaId, that Hibernate is told to re-use for saving two different Java references, resulting in the collision.
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @EmbeddedId
    private FooId id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn( name = "alphaId"/*__________________    */
                    ,referencedColumnName = "userId"),/* \   */
        @JoinColumn( name = "betaId"/*_________________   |  */         
                    ,referencedColumnName = "barId")/* \  |  */
    })/*                                                | |  */ 
    private Bar alphaBar;/*                             | |  */ 
    /*                                                  | |  */ 
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)/*                 | |  */ 
    @JoinColumns({/*                                    | |  */ 
        @JoinColumn( name = "betaId"/*already used_____/  |  */
                    ,referencedColumnName = "userId"),/*  |  */
        @JoinColumn( name = "alphaId"/*already used______/   */
                    ,referencedColumnName = "barId")
    })
    private Bar betaBar;
}

From the db's perspective, there's no difference between alphaBar and betaBar, because they're encoded by the same two columns in Foo's table on the db.
It's all fine from the Java perspective: these are all valid references to different objects. The decorators instructing Hibernate how to map them to a relational structure are to blame for confusing the alpha and beta Bars.
Assuming that you want each Foo to be related to two (possibly different) Bars, you need to let the alphaBar use its own two columns and give another two to be used for betaBar:
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @EmbeddedId
    private FooId id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "alphaBarUserId", referencedColumnName = "userId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "alphaBarBarId", referencedColumnName = "barId")
    })
    private Bar alphaBar;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "betaBarUserId", referencedColumnName = "userId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "betaBarBarId", referencedColumnName = "barId")
    })
    private Bar betaBar;
}

Depending on your PhysicalNamingStrategy that dictates how Hibernate maps your field names in Java to column names in PostgreSQL, it's possible Foo's composite primary key is also trying to use those same two columns, because FooId is also constructed with an alphaId and betaId fields. If Hibernate translates that literally to "alphaId" and "betaId", it would mean Foo gets just one pair of columns and tries to save all three things (its own composite identifier as well as the two references) in the same one pair of columns.

Another way to solve this issue is to use 2 classes Bar1 and Bar2.
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @EmbeddedId
    private FooId id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "alphaId", referencedColumnName = "userId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "betaId", referencedColumnName = "barId")
    })
    private Bar1 alphaBar;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "alphaId", referencedColumnName = "barId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "betaId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
    })
    private Bar2 betaBar;
}

@Entity
public class Bar1 {
    @EmbeddedId
    private BarId1 id;
}

@Entity
public class Bar2 {
    @EmbeddedId
    private BarId2 id;
}

@Embeddable
public class FooId {
    private String alphaId;
    private String betaId;
}

@Embeddable
public class BarId1 {
    private String userId;
    private String barId;
}

@Embeddable
public class BarId2 {
    private String barId;
    private String userId;
    
}

Update : I add BarId1 and BarId2 to be more consistent.

It looked elegant at first glance, but that would break referential integrity of the model. It's still writing the alphaBar and betaBar pair of identifiers to the same one pair of columns on the database, so at any given time only one of these will match an existing entity. In OP's current model, they at least point at a valid Bar. Here, when Bar2 identifiers get written to those two columns and your model attempts to find a Bar1 based on them, it won't find one. Those keys correspond to a Bar2 and either don't exist for any Bar1, or happen point at a random, accidental one.

The edit makes it more repetitive, not consistent. It's again rearranging things in Java while the problem remains in the two columns in PostgreSQL that Hibernate is told to re-use for saving two different references, resulting in the collision.

In postgres it will be to table bar1 and bar2 so there will be no collision. But maybe there is some constraints that I don't see.

Yes, Bar1 and Bar2 get separate tables, but Foo stays with just one pair of columns that's able to only save a single link to a single one of those, either Bar1 or Bar2 while the model on Java side it wants to link to both.

Yes it works only at insert time, after you can't update anything. So it works with delete / insert pattern not the best way.

It might work and I don't think there's anything preventing updates, but it doesn't solve OP's problem: the Foo on the db is still only able to link a single Bar at a time. If you update either alphaBar or betaBar on it, they both get updated because they keep their info in the same two columns. If you delete the Foo instance/row and replace it by inserting a new one, the new one has the exact same problem: there's just one pair of columns, so it can only fit one link, to one Bar.

I'am not sure of that you can save both BarX in same time, at insert time.
